# Catch onFling on ListView

Tags: android, image, listview, lazy-evaluation, onfling

I'd like to catch the event `onFling` on a ListView. My goal is to load images from the internet in my listview adapter only if I'm not on an onFling event. I found a snippet few months ago but I'm not able to find it today...

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably looking for
[this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/01/19/shelves-an-open-source-android-application/)